# Run macro when cell value is changed by form control element

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using a drop down list (Form control, not data validation), which gets it's data from `AC2:AC300`. **AC1** indicates the chosen option; When the user chooses the value in **AC2**, the value in `AC1=1`, **AC3** means `2`, **AC4** is `3` etc.

I've used the following code to run when the value of **AC1** changes. it runs like a beauty when I manually change the value, but won't do a damn thing when it's changed by the drop down. It even won't run when I use `=AC1` in a cell and use that cell in my code.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range


    Set KeyCells = Range("AC1")

   If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

        Worksheets("Geschichte").Range("AD1:AE400").ClearContents
        Getsubfolders
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried Worksheet_Calculate ?

Comment: Do you mean a combo box? Why not use the drop down change event - right click and assign macro?

Comment: Wow. that was real stupid. i was under the assumption it'd run the macro when the combobox was activated, and i needed to run it after a value was chosen.

Comment: @SJR Make an answer for future references to this question please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment, right-click on your control and select Assign Macro. In the dialog box press New and enter your code.
[image]

Comment: Works like a charm - Thank you